refactoring helm template files for single object and array of objects
I need help with refactoring the template files in helm
Below is the config.yaml template file -
{{- define "service.config" -}}
{{- $config := .Values.config}}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: {{ $config.name }}
  annotations:
    config.type: {{ $config.type }}
    config.policy: {{ $config.policy }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

Below is the configs.yaml template file -
{{- define "service.configs" -}}
{{- range $config := .Values.configs}}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: {{ $config.name }}
  annotations:
    config.type: {{ $config.type }}
    config.policy: {{ $config.policy }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}


you can see the config is for single value and configs is for array of values.
how can I refactor this?

How much of the Job specification is in the config(s) structure?  Would it be more effective to write each Job into a separate templates/some-job.yaml file?

Both templates you show at least superficially seem fine.  What specific problem are you running into?
